# Initialize service account and clound functions together-Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts

How can I initialize cloud functions and service account together. In my index.ts file I have already initialized functions using

`admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);`

but now I want to create create custom token with firebase, so I created a service account and added the `service-account.json` in my functions folder and added

```
const serviceAccount = require("./service-account.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://functionstest-54bd9 .firebaseio.com"
});
```

above initialize functions. but when I tried to deploy the function, i got this error in the console

```
Error: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initializeApp() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initializeApp() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initializeApp() to give each app a unique name.
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/home/me/Documents/TfmFirebase/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
    at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/home/me/Documents/TfmFirebase/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:85:28)
```

I have only one app and I have added only a service account. Do I have to create another app just  to create the custom token only? How can I fix this?

**Update1**

This is how I am creating custom token,

```
//create user
let writeResult = await db.collection('users').add({
                    user: user,
                    password: password,
                    isBlocked: false,
                    joiningDate: Date.now(),
                    phoneVerified: false,
                    deleted: false,
                    contacts:{
                        phone: phone
                    }
                })

//create token
let tokenSnapShot = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(writeResult.id);
const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(writeResult.id);
let updateResult = await userRef.get();
t.update(userRef,{ "token": updateResult.data() });
```

Please correct me if I am doing it wrong

Comment: `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);` should allow you to create custom tokens. Why do you need to use the service account too?

Comment: I am not using sign in methods provided by firebase, because my app requires some more fields while registering the user. so registering is done in a cloud function and I am using the document id to create custom token, so that i can access it in firebase security rules. Can i use the document id as auth id in firebase rules?

Comment: "*I am using the document id to create custom token*" I'm not sure how that works. Maybe you could post your function code?

Comment: @Sidney i have updated my question

Comment: It looks like you're storing all of your user data in your database. Is there a reason you aren't using firebase auth for storing passwords and handling authentication?

Comment: In sign in methods, there are only phone number sign in and email/password sign with other federated providers, I am requesting username, phone and gender on signup

Comment: Hey did you find a solution to this? I am running into the exact same issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just was working on the same subject. When you work on at your localhost. You will need extra security to access your database. So, you will need to admin [service key](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk) while working at localhost, and you may [emulate only HTTPS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) functions. While working at firebase hosting you do not need this account key. But works fine either. Then you need to remove at your above code either

```
1.admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

or

```
const serviceAccount = require("./service-account.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://functionstest-54bd9 .firebaseio.com"
});
```

Comment: I am not using local server, i am deploying functions to firebase and accessing from there. I tried with only `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);` that gave me error stating that it requires a private key

Comment: If you have deployed the service key to the firebase hosting then use second choice only and delete the first line. `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase); `

Comment: And consider the service-account.json is original file name that you downloaded from the link :https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk and be sure the path. At your situation this file seams to be located under `/functions /` root.

Comment: sorry, i didn't get this `if you have...` i have to use the service account every time when i register a user

Comment: the `service-account.json` is located inside the functions folder

Comment: If you work on firebase hosting, you don't have to have a service account key. just `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase); ` is enough. BTW, when I downloaded the service account key. the original key name is seems: [appname]-firebase-adminsdk-9fnzd-310260a0c4.json , I mean this key.json should be hard guessed name.

Comment: i am not using firebase hosting for now, only cloud functions, for serving data to my mobile app. and i have edited the downloaded json file name to service-account.json

Comment: You said above: `I am not using local server, i am deploying functions to firebase and accessing from there. ` That I mean. You don't need a service key file.

Comment: but when i tried to create custom token from cloud function it gives error, create custom requires private key, that is why i added service account