# firebase-admin, is it contradicting to use default credentials and serviceAccountId in same initialization?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin, google-iam

I initialize `firebase-admin` like so for `firebase functions`:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const { applicationDefault } = require('firebase-admin/app')

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: applicationDefault(),
  serviceAccountId: 'firebase-adminsdk-hash@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
})
```

I had to add the `serviceAccountId` so that I could access another IAM permission. But I'm not sure if it's now unnecessary use `applicationDefault()` as well. **Does anyone know if this is considered redundant / contradicting?**

Answer (score 1):

The short answer, in my opinion, would be: yes, it is redundant and inconsistent to specify the `applicationDefault` parameter as it is implicitly populated from the `FIREBASE_CONFIG` environment variable as explained in this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736399/differences-when-initializing-app-with-firebase-admin-using-empty-params-admin). (Please be aware the initialization can be different depending on the [environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974879/using-firebase-admin-what-are-service-account-credentials-used-for)).

*Here is a comparison from [initializing the service account and the Cloud Functions together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137429/initialize-service-account-and-clound-functions-together-firebase) and [impersonating the service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69698406/is-it-possible-to-initialize-the-firebase-admin-sdk-with-an-impersonated-service).*

---

To get a more detailed explanation, we will need to dive into the documentation; we can see that the [`initializeApp()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.app.md#initializeapp) function has the [`AppOptions`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.app.appoptions.md#appoptionscredential) parameter (interface), where you can specify the [`serviceAccountId`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.app.appoptions.md#appoptionsserviceaccountid).

Finally, you can check all the [functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.app.md#functions) from **firebase-admin/app module**, and get this description for the `applicationDefault(httpAgent)` function:

> Returns a credential created from the [Google Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) that grants admin access to Firebase services. This credential can be used in the call to [initializeApp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.app.md#initializeapp).
>
> Google Application Default Credentials are available on any Google infrastructure, such as Google App Engine and Google Compute Engine. See [Initialize the SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk) for more details.